# How to print a list of keys from a dictionary with a specific

Tags: python, python-3.x

At the moment I'm currently trying to check a dictionary of items and go through them checking for a value. If the value is more than 0 then it prints it in a list, otherwise its ignored and it goes on. Currently I have this code typed out :

```py
from items import items

for item in items:
    if items[item][6] < 0:
        print("You have ", item[6], " of ", item[0], " .")
```

But from here I'm pretty confused as to how to continue with this. I'm getting an index error but I'm not sure what its for.

Comment: Can you share an example of `items`' content?

Comment: @Mureinik Gotcha. Here you go.
`,'Broken Watch': ('Broken Watch', 'This is a watch. It appears to be shattered, and the hands are no longer moving.', 'Item', 'Junk', 1, 1, 0)`

Comment: From your item sample it looks like you are using a dictionary, my answer below shows how you can iterate over it nicely

Comment: @Randolph Use try and except IndexError and in except, print that dictionary value. I think an element in dictionary has less than 7 elements in tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over a dictionary where the key is the item's name and the value is a tuple with some information in it.

You could do it like this Note this will only work if your tuple **ALWAYS** has the same structure / number of fields.

```
In [23]: my_items = {'Broken Watch': ('Broken Watch', 'This is a watch. It appears to be shattered, and the hands are no longer moving.', 'Item', 'Junk', 1, 1, 0), 'Watch that will
    ...:  print': ('Some stuff', 'More stuff', 'Item', 'Junk', 1, 1, 7)}                                                                                                            

In [24]: for name, info in my_items.items(): 
    ...:     num= info[6] 
    ...:     print("Checking num", num) 
    ...:     if num > 0: 
    ...:         print("You have", num, "of", name, ".") 
    ...:          
    ...:          
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                            
Checking num 0
Checking num 7
You have 7 of Watch that will print .
```

Comment: I attempted to use this but instead it throws this error :

"num = info[6]
IndexError: tuple index out of range"

Comment: @Randolph, you probably need to check the length of your tuple, or validate that it has the correct length, if you are getting IndexError then that field does not exist

Comment: I eventually managed to figure it out! It just came down to me going through and making sure all of them were all the same length.

Comment: Awewome!!  if this helped you please mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

You aren't subscripting `item` properly. `item` is a key in `items`, and you have to relate to it as such (like you did in the `if` statement). Note, also, that according to the question's text, you probably meant to use the `>` operator, not `<` :

```
for item in items:
    if items[item][6] > 0: 
        print("You have ", items[item][6], " of ", items[item][0], " .")
```

As a side note, all the values you need seem to be in the value tuple, so you could just iterate over the values instead of the using the keys to access them:

```
for item in items.values():
    if item[6] > 0: 
        print("You have ", item[6], " of ", item[0], " .")
```

Comment: I tried using the second method you gave me and it threw this error
"IndexError : tuple index out of range"
Any fixes?

Comment: @Randolph this snippet seems to work with the input you provided. Could you share the input that causes that error?